# Installing Windows Server AppFabric - Unknown user name or bad password

Tags: configuration, appfabric

I'm installing Windows Server AppFabric in a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 that is part of my domain. On the Configure Hosting Service, I would like to configure each AppFabric service on a separate Domain account. I've created the 3 necessary databases on a separate database server that is also part of my domain, and 3 domain users, and I've given each domain user db_owner privilege on it's respective database. 
When I'm installing Windows Server AppFabric, and I try to set the monitoring configuration, and on the AppFabric Event Collection service account, I'm trying to use the domain user, but it keeps giving me **Logon Failure: Unknown username or bad password**, but the user and password are valid! On the same server, if I do a runas with the same domain user and password, I open any application I want. 
Is there a restriction on using domain accounts for this? I've placed all 3 accounts as local admin and on AS_Administrators, to see if it helped, but it's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of troubleshooting, I found out how to configure it. Before the Windows Server AppFabric Configuration Wizard is opened, go to the Services, and configure the 3 services (AppFabricCachingService, AppFabricEventCollectionService and AppFabricWorkflowManagementService) with the domain users you want. Then, you open the Wizard, and the correct domain users will already be configured, and all you need to do is configure the database.
The post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733348/configuring-appfabric-with-remote-database also helped, along with the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637739.aspx